# Why do we need DNS?

Tags: ip, dns

The case for DNS usually goes like this: People like names. Computers like numbers. So we let people use domain names and use DSN to convert them to IP numbers and everybody is happy.

But IP numbers, domains names and every other single thing processed by a computer are really just human abstractions. So, in principle, there is no such a thing as IP numbers are "easy for computers to digest". I can imagine a system where a machine is reachable by using its domain name alone, without all the hassle of translating it to an IP.

Of course, I'm missing something here, so I ask smarter people: why do we need to translate domain names to IPs? Why not skipping that part? Is this for historical reasons or is there an advantage of using IPs instead of names that also make sense to humans?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 and questions soliciting primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic here. You may be able to get an answer on [sf], but they may closing as generating primarily opinion-based answers, too.

Comment: It’s partly historical — packet based switching was developed when computers had much less power than today. But it’s also a fundamental feature of routing. You should read more about that.

Comment: We humans are better at dealing with names, so we give the numbers names - actually more than one name for a single number. The computer needs numbers because that's what computers do. And IP (v4/v6) uses numbers in its protocol. If you wanted to use CLNP with NSAP, then you can use words in the address, but they're still numbers on the wire.

Comment: Yes, the "dot quad" is a human construct, but it's just decimal equivalent of four eight bit values which make up a 32bit IPv4 address. IPv6 has a similar human textual notation. In every man-machine interaction, the machine has to deal with some level of human language because we don't think and interact with ones and zeros.

Comment: Even if for nothing else, using IP numbers only, how would you handle it if you needed to renumber your computers (e.g. move to a different network)? You'd have to notify every user in the world of the change and they would have to change all their records to point to the new address, all at the same instant.  One level of indirection avoids all those problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can do calculations on IP addresses, not on domain names. This allows you to do subnetting, aggregation, route comparison, and many more things.

These functions are needed to do route selection, comparison, lookups, etc. If you'd use names, these things wouldn't be possible, or at least not as efficiently as it is with numbers. Routing tables would become impossibly long, making lookups costly.